# stylesheet_link_tag producing absolute links instead of relative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker, tunneling

I set up facebooker to tunnel my Ruby on Rails application.

The issue is that I would like to test locally. That is, I don't want to have to start a tunnel every time I want to see my changes.

Right now, when I start the application using `ruby script/server` (not calling `rake facebooker:tunnel:background_start` beforehand), links created by helpers (e.g., stylesheet_link_tag, javascript_include_tag, image_tag) are prepended with my tunnlr address: http://web1.tunnlr.com:myPort/. (For example, a CSS link looks like this in the page source: http://web1.tunnlr.com:myPort//stylesheets/appName.css?1234567890.)

I don't want that functionality; I can't see my CSS or JavaScript changes without having to start the tunnel first. I want the links to be relative, not absolute. So, `stylesheet_link_tag` should produce `/stylesheets/appName.css?1234567890`.

Does anyone know why it's doing that in the first place and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The AssetTagHelper uses your `asset_host` URL.  I am not sure whether `facebooker` is setting it for you (I don't know much about facebooker), but you can reset it in your view no problem:

Before your `stylesheet_link_tab` just override the host URL:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "localhost:3000"
# or
ActionController::Base.asset_host = ""
```

So using ERB it might look like this:

```
<% ActionController::Base.asset_host = "" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet.css" %>
```

Walabing!

Comment: It's better to place the setting into config/environments/development.rb

Comment: +1 Depending on the context you may be able to do `ActionController::Base.asset_host = root_url[0..-2]` (the `[0..-2]` to trim the trailing slash)